# Spring security Oauth2 jwt to configure different authenticationManagers to authentication different type of users

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have configured Authorization server as follows which works fine.

But my requirement is that I have two different databases to authenticate two different type of users.
How can I configure two authenticationMangers(UserDetailsServices) to authenticate them.

```
@Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter() {

             JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new CustomTokenEnhancer();
             // JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();


            KeyPair keyPair = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(
                    new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"), "foobar".toCharArray())
                    .getKeyPair("test");


            converter.setKeyPair(keyPair);
            return converter;
        }



        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).accessTokenConverter(
                    jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        }


        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
                throws Exception {
            oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess(
                    "isAuthenticated()");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("bootApp")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                .secret("bootAppSecreat")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120);
        }
    }
```

Can we have two AuthenticationServers in single App which will solve my problem.